# Cannot pass this issue: The constructor JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(PublicKey) is undefined

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Trying to decrypt a file which for my Cryptografy class, but I cannot pass the correct arguments for the function:

```
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedDataParser;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.RecipientInformationStore;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.Streams;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class BouncyCastleDecrypt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            FileInputStream certFileInputStream = new FileInputStream("xxxx.crt");
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(certFileInputStream);

            FileInputStream encryptedFileInputStream = new FileInputStream("xxxx.enc");
            CMSEnvelopedDataParser parser = new CMSEnvelopedDataParser(encryptedFileInputStream);

            RecipientInformationStore recipientInfos = parser.getRecipientInfos();
            RecipientInformation recipientInfo = recipientInfos.getRecipients().iterator().next();

            JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient recipient = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(cert.getPublicKey());
            byte[] decryptedData = recipientInfo.getContent(recipient);

            OutputStream decryptedOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("final_file.pdf");
            decryptedOutputStream.write(decryptedData);
            decryptedOutputStream.close();

            System.out.println("Descriptografia concluída com sucesso!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Multiple variations in order to create the receipient to access the key

Comment: You might want to phrase the title as a question... please see advice on the StackOverflow help article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Specifically they suggest writing your title last "If you're having trouble summarizing the problem, write the title last—sometimes, writing the rest of the question first can make it easier to describe the problem."

Comment: I'm not familiar with `BouncyCastle`. But, Google found the [class JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient API](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/index.html?org/bouncycastle/cms/jcajce/JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient.html). Note that the *only* constructor takes a `java.security.PrivateKey`  Object for an argument. You are trying to pass a PublicKey.